# Стилистическая правка фразы

Tags: стилистика, редактура

Редактирую перевод.  Когда игроки пытаются отказаться от все более сложных задач, они сталкиваются со смертельными последствиями **и тут же понимают:** "Исполни желание, или желание исполнится само".

When players attempt to refuse the increasingly challenging tasks, they’re met with deadly consequences, quickly discovering: you must do the dare, or the dare does you.

Вопрос: как грамотно отредактировать выделенную часть? Дело в тон, что теряется  при переводе: **"и тут же понимают...."**. Но тогда теряется связь с последующей частью: " Исполни желание, или желание исполнится само".

When players attempt to refuse the increasingly challenging tasks, they’re met with deadly consequences, quickly discovering: you must do the dare, or the dare does you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не там ошибку ищете.

> you must do the dare, or the dare does you

Здесь непереводимая игра слов. Глагол to do многозначный. В первом случаю он действительно означает "исполнить", во втором - "сделать" в разговорном значении "победить". Вам прежде всего надо думать, как перевести эту часть, предлагаемые варианты никуда не годятся,  а уж основное предложение подогнать под этот смысл не проблема. Да, собственно, перевод основной части вполне адекватен.

Я бы перевел (в первом приближении, естественно) так:

***Когда игроки сталкиваются с необходимостью отказаться от решения всё более сложных задач, они сталкиваются с фатальными последствиями, сразу понимая, что обязаны сделать вызов или вызов "сделает" их.***

Comment: behemothus,спасибо!

Comment: С этой частью проблем не было. Смысл, как я уже писал, в том, если участники не исполнят желание, оно само исполнится.

Comment: @plotnikov.tosha2016  *Смысл, как я уже писал, в том..." - я прокрнсультировался у одного знатока, жду ответа от второго. Пока ваше понимание выглядит придуманным. Но если вы уверены, то остается только думать, что это отсылка к какой-то известной мудрости, преломлояемой под контекст.  Ну или это какая-то уже двухуровневая игра слов, совсем уж непереводимая... А можно ознакомится с английским контекстом?!

Comment: Ой, как я сразу не догадался погуглить... Нашел я этот текст. Вы меня извините, но по аннотации ни о никаких желаниях там речи не идет. https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7126746/

Comment: Это игра "Правда или действия" (Thrust or dare). Смысл её мне понятен. Dare, конечно, в определенном контексте можно перевести как желание, но без пояснений это будет совершенно непонятно.  В русском есть что-то типа "игра на желание", проигравший выполняет желание выигравшего. Игра, понятно, совсем другая, но смысл термина "желания" именно тот, это желание не игрока, а какое действие, ему поручаемое...

Comment: Короче, ещё раз призывают поменять перевод этой части.

Comment: Фильм называется "Правда или желание". По сюжету, друзья приезжают в заброшенной дом с дурной славой и сталкиваются с призраком, который заставляет играть их в эту игру. Когда игрок отказывался, желание исполнялось само. В фильме так и перевели.

Comment: Так что я ничего не выдумываю!

Comment: Да я же всё нашел. Это перевод так называется. И перевод этот плохой. Я спросил у своих американцев, будет ли ими принят ваш перевод. Если вдруг будет, соглашусь с вами.

Answer (score 2):

**В качестве варианта:**

When players attempt to refuse the increasingly challenging tasks, they’re met with deadly consequences, quickly discovering: you must do the dare, or the dare does you.

**Машинный перевод:**

Когда игроки пытаются отказаться от все более сложных задач, они сталкиваются со смертельными последствиями, быстро обнаруживая: вы должны сделать вызов или вызов сделает вас

**Редактирование:**

Когда игроки пытаются отказаться от все более сложных задач, они сталкиваются со смертельными последствиями, **так как должны быстро принять решение**: вы должны сделать вызов (ход) **или вызов (ход)  будет сделан за вас.**

Понимание конечной фазы вызывает у меня затруднение: возможно, какой-то ход в игре будет сделан от вашего имени, но без вашего участия.

Запятая перед ИЛИ не ставится по правилам (при наличии общей бессоюзной связи).

Comment: Sharon, вроде все верно: но все-таки нестыковка. Принять решение: какое? Да. Это игра, в которой участник должен ответить правду на вопрос или исполнить желание. Это описание к фильму. Сюжет фильма таков: если участник не исполнит желание исполнится самим.

Comment: С запятой согласен.

Comment: Сложная ситуация, dare - это точно желание, а то в словаре такого значения нет. Если в фильме ситуация обозначена,  а игрок не хочет делать ход, то действие будет сделано по отношению к нему. Правду за него никто не скажет, тогда  он станет объектом чьего-то желания? Да, смысл не очень ясный, надо хорошо знать текст и правила игры.

Comment: Вот только подсказали: quickly discovering - становится ясно:

Comment: Это то же, что "фант" в известной у нас игре. Truth or Dare русская википедия переводит как "правда или действие". Мой вариант: _Когда играющие стали уклоняться от выполнения усложняющихся заданий, они столкнулись с губительными последствиями, вскоре осознав: с заданием нужно справиться, иначе оно тебя погубит._

Comment: Alex_ander, да, вы правы. Мне больше нравится: правда или желание. Все-таки на бумажках пишется желание, которое игрок должен исполнить.

Comment: @ Sharon друзья приезжают в загородном дом, который имеет дурную славу. Там они играют в эту игру. Но в игру вступает дух, они решают прекратить. Но дух заставляет их продолжать игру. Если они откажутся выполнять желание, желание само будут выполнено за них.

Comment: Вы немного искажаете смысл фразы. Первая часть правильная :«или вы справитесь с желанием/ но лучше с заданием» и вторая с тем же глаголом , но действие должно быть направлено в обратную сторону: « или оно с вами». Quickly discovering -- быстро сообразив.

Comment: – V.V, нет, не то. С предложением про желание нет проблем.  Quickly discovering -- быстро сообразив. Вот с этой были проблемы.

Comment: @plotnikov В этом контексте _to do smb._ направлено _на человека_ и означает примерно то же, что и _to do for_ (расправиться, разделаться, доконать). Словарный пример: _I'll **do you** even if it's my last act in life. — Я разделаюсь с тобой, даже если это будет стоить мне жизни._

Comment: И какое там «желание», если прямо стоит "tasks". "исполнится само", неверно, в тексте "dare does you". Где вы видите «само»?

Comment: V.V, зачем применять дословный перевод? К тому же, в фильме, если участники не исполняют желание, оно само исполняется. Отсюда и такой перевод. В фильме тоже так перевели.

Comment: @plotnikov.tosha2016 *Если участники не исполняют желание, оно само исполняется*  - тогда это вообще другой смысл. Без еонтекста переводить невозможно.

Comment: То, что в фильме плохо перевели, не образец, и не новость, к сожалению. У вас же в арсенале интересная игра слов. Но не нужно do переводить как "делать". Кальки в переводе не приветствуются. Но раз вопросы задаете, уже хорошо. Удачи !

Comment: Продублирую ссылку.  https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7126746/ В разделе Storyline все достаточно понятно. А вот то, во что они играют. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%B0_%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5%3F

Comment: ЗЫ тормознул ночью сначала, не вчитался в то, о чем Alex_ander и V.V. говорят, и  дал свой ответ. Сейчас признаю ваш приоритет.

Comment: – V.V, конечно, переводить do  как "делать'' не стоит. Желание, задание в данном случае контекстуальные синонимы.